# Possible approach for product mockup creation including distortion created through perspective

Tags: 3d, projections

I am not an expert in 3D nor computer graphics. Please forgive me if I use wrong wording.

High level problem description: For an online shop, I would like to create mockup images of apparel (t-shirts, tank tops, hoodies) with a print placed on them. There are loads of information how to do this with photoshop, but I would like to have an automated way to handle this. The image manipulation should happen with imagemagick finally.

The images should be captured on a dummy under a controlled setting. The image creation should include following steps:

- Capture a image from the front of a white shirt.
- Capture a series of images of the dummy with the shirt as the dummy rotates around itself to create a photogrammetry 3D model of the dummy with the shirt.

The image taken from the front will be the basis of the product image later on. The 3D model should be used to create analyse the distortion which has to be applied to the design/print on the shirt. This is the step i am interested in.

The image composition should happen in this steps:

- use the image from the front as the base.
- Extract the shadows of the image.
- Blend a color layer over the shirt, to get the different product color.
- Map the design (a graphic or a text) over the white shirt using a distortion method to squeeze and pull apart the design following the perspective change created through the shape of the dummy.

My idea had been to use a 3D method an image of a grid as the design on the 3D model somehow and analyse the the created 2D image for the distortion of the grid to get a model of how to squeeze and pull the design then in the image stacking process.

Do you have any recommendations how to do this in practical steps? Or can you suggest me an different approach to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This webpage demonstrates a ***simple*** program [MakeHuman](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/wiki/Video:Unity) which allows to easily create human models, add clothing etc. You would need to create your own custom clothing files to dress the models with specific clothes rather than the ones that are included. All of this is possible but it's not simple to do. These models can be exported to Blender and controlled with Python. Neither of us knows how you would do this with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) it doesn't have those features.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will have a look into this for sure.